# Lync Client SDK: FollowedRooms not working on wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, lync

I've been trying to make a lync wpf application for persistent chat,
I did before something like it on silverlight application and it worked fine.

there seems to be some difference between the wpf and silverlight LyncClient but I cannot seem to find anything on the web.

my code is:

```
LyncClient _client = LyncClient.getClient();
if (_client.state == ClientState.SignedIn)
{
   if (_client.RoomManager.State == RoomManagerState.Enabled)
   {
      if (_client.RoomManager.FollowedRooms == null)
      {
         MessageBox.show("not working");
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox.show("working");
      }
   }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I found it was a problem with the client.
I had installed RTM version and it isnt supported there,
after installing some kbs it worked.